# How to filter rows of a dataframe based on the value of a column and the next in that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a Dataframe called "df" and a column in that dataframe that we can call "col".

Based on the value in "col", I need to keep in the dataframe (to filter) only the values where col[i] is different of the value col[i+2] and the same of col[i+1]. Indeed is the penultimate of a sequence of the same value in the column.

If I have:

```
Index  a   b   col
0      34  56   1 
1      45  23   1
2      11  17   1
3      45  67   2
4      12  12   2
5       1   3   3
6      98  12   3
```

I need:

```
1      45  23   1
3      45  67   2
5       1   3   3
```

I use this code:

```
def penultimate(df, col):
    d = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(1, len(df.index)-2):
       if((df[col].iloc[i] != df[col].iloc[i + 2]) and (df[col].iloc[i] == df[col].iloc[i + 1])):
            d = d.append(df.loc[i])
    return d
```

And it works, but is too slow with big dataframes. There is a method to do this in a faster way?

Thank you

Comment: `df.loc[df['col'].ne(df['col'].shift(-2)) & df['col'].eq(df['col'].shift(-1))]`?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `.shift` twice and vectorized comparison `==`

```
df[(df.col == df.col.shift(-1)) & (df.col != df.col.shift(-2))]
```

---

```
   Index   a   b  col
1      1  45  23    1
3      3  45  67    2
5      5   1   3    3
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment on my last answer. I can not watch the video. Could you pass the link again? I didn't know how to contact you

Comment: @ansev The link is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEUXKG97YRw) ;) upvote this comment when you get the link for me to remove afterwards !